# ESLint print all fixes to terminal

Tags: eslint

When I run ESLint with the `--fix` flag, I'd like for the changes made to be output to the terminal. By default it displays no output except for errors or warnings that cannot be fixed, [as the ESLint docs say](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--fix):

> The fixes are made to the actual files themselves and only the remaining unfixed issues are output.

Is there any way to force ESLint to print all the issues that were fixed to the terminal?

For the sake of clarity, here's the command I'm currently running: `eslint src --fix --ext js,ts,tsx`.

Comment: You can see the options the CLI offers on that page, what it fixed isn't one of them. What are you hoping to use this for?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm just hoping to get a quick way to review what was changed. A previous project I was working on used a linter (I think tslint?) that printed the changes and I used that to catch debugging lines I had quickly added without proper syntax (like missing `;`) or spacing and had forgotten to remove later.

I've just been working around it by looking reviewing the local changes with git, but it would just be easier to view them in a terminal.

Comment: Rather than put this on the linter, I generally use `git add -p` (preceded by `git add . -N` to start tracking new files, if there are any) to explicitly review the changes and decide what I want to go into the staging area to be committed. This makes it easy to split changes into multiple commits or drop unneeded changes entirely. See e.g. https://www.nadiaodunayo.com/writing/2018/05/28/tell-git-your-intentions.

Comment: Awesome that's super helpful. Thank you!